# python scapy sendp() execution time

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

Good day.

I have a cycle, and using scapy sendp() inside

```
startPTime = datetime.now()
sendp(ping_frame, verbose=False)
stopPTime = datetime.now()
calcTime = stopPTime - startPTime
print (f'{startPTime} - {stopPTime} ({calcTime})')
```

and I see a big difference in execution on different computers:

python3.9, Windows10, Ryzen 5 3600:

```
2021-09-30 17:03:55.395827 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.395827 (0:00:00)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.395827 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.396828 (0:00:00.001001)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.396828 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.396828 (0:00:00)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.396828 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.398052 (0:00:00.001224)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.398052 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.398630 (0:00:00.000578)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.398630 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.399212 (0:00:00.000582)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.399212 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.399212 (0:00:00)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.399212 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.400213 (0:00:00.001001)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.400213 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.400213 (0:00:00)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.401214 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.401724 (0:00:00.000510)
2021-09-30 17:03:55.401724 - 2021-09-30 17:03:55.401724 (0:00:00)
```

python3.8, Ubuntu 18.04, Xeon E5504:

```
2021-09-30 16:58:25.975924 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.014881 (0:00:00.038957)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.014957 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.063570 (0:00:00.048613)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.063644 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.106817 (0:00:00.043173)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.106894 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.154930 (0:00:00.048036)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.155011 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.199208 (0:00:00.044197)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.199286 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.235903 (0:00:00.036617)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.235980 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.282214 (0:00:00.046234)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.282288 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.327702 (0:00:00.045414)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.327777 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.362953 (0:00:00.035176)
2021-09-30 16:58:26.363025 - 2021-09-30 16:58:26.403885 (0:00:00.040860)
```

Why is there so big difference? How can i reduce this time?

This 5ms on Ubuntu/Xeon became 75 seconds if i trying generate 1500 packets. On Windows, the same 1500 packets are generated in less than 2 seconds.

Thank you.